# Implementing Yahtzee in SML

Tags: sml, poker

I'm writing an SML Yahtzee/Poker Program that receives a list as an input in the format

`yahtzee(1,3,3,4,3)`

in which each number is a result of a dice roll, and then prints the corresponding result, which in this case would be

`(three-of-a-kind, 14)`

the last number being the sum of all 5 dices received as input in this case.

I currently take the string and count the occurrences of each number with a count variable, since there are 6 possibilities of outcomes on a dice roll - either 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6.

I sort the counts in ascending order so that the last number of my new list gives me some info regarding what "hand" that could be, out of the following:

yahtzee - which is 5 of a kind and is "worth" 50 points so the return would be `(yahtzee, 50)`
large straight - 5 number sequence, worth 40 points so returns `(large-straight, 40)`
small straight - 4 number sequence, 30 points so `(small-straight, 30)`
full house - 3 of a kind and two of another kind, 25 points so `(full-house, 25)`
four of a kind - worth as many points as the sum of all 5 dices, so `(four-of-a-kind, sum)`
three of a kind - worth as many points as the sum of all 5 dices, so `(three-of-a-kind, sum)`
chance - `(chance, sum)`

Because also I don't care what number occurs 3 times, for example, because it would be a three-of-a-kind regardless. By checking the last number I can have a pretty good notion of what is going on.

And for the full-house, if I check the number before the last and that is equal to 2, I know it's a full house, because the last it's going to be 3. It is important to note that if the sum of a full house is greater than 25, however, that hand should be three of a kind instead, because it yields a larger amount of points.

I haven't implemented all cases yet, and so the code below is what I currently have, and the last function is an attempt to test if I'm going towards the right direction but that would be renamed to `yahtzee(L)` later so it can receive the input.

```ml
fun counter (nil, count1:int, count2:int, count3:int, count4:int, count5:int, count6:int) = ListMergeSort.sort (fn (x,y) => x > y) [count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6]
    | counter (6::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6+1)
    | counter (5::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5+1, count6)
    | counter (4::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1, count2, count3, count4+1, count5, count6)
    | counter (3::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1, count2, count3+1, count4, count5, count6)
    | counter (2::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1, count2+1, count3, count4, count5, count6)
    | counter (1::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = counter (t, count1+1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6)
    | counter (h::t, count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6) = ListMergeSort.sort (fn (x,y) => x > y) [count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6];

fun sum (nil) = 0
    | sum (h::t) = h + sum(t)

fun anyOfAKind (nil) = 0
    | anyOfAKind (L) = List.last(L)

fun fullHouse (nil) = 0
    | fullHouse (L) = List.nth(L, 3)

fun testdice (nil) = []
    | testdice (L) = 
        let 
            val listSum = sum(L)
            val count = counter(L,0,0,0,0,0,0)
        in
            if fullHouse(count) = 2 then
                if listSum <= 25 then print "(fullhouse, 25)"
                else print "(threeofakind, " ^ Int.toString (sum) ^ ")"
        end;
```

If I remove the last function there are no problems with building the file, however, with the last function in place I get the error message

`Error: syntax error found at END`

My first question is, why do I get this error message?

I think I need to return something but am not?

And another question I have is if my thought process is looking good and if not any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You're getting the syntax error because one of your `if`s is missing its `else` clause.

Comment: Another problem is that one clause of `testdice` produces a list, while the other produces `unit`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several major problems:

1. You have an `if` that doesn't have a matching `else`. That's your syntax problem.
2. Once you get that sorted, `testdice` wants to either produce a list, or print something and produce `unit`. A function's clauses can't have different types.
3. `nil` is just a name, and in a pattern it matches everything. It's not a data constructor - the "empty list" constructor is `[]`.

I'm going to assume that the function is actually supposed to produce a pair, not print a string with a specific format.
I am also assuming that the input is a list, as you say - not a quintuple, as in the example.
(It's not difficult to rewrite from one form to the other.)

First, define a suitable data type:

```
datatype Hand = Yahtzee
              | LargeStraight
              | SmallStraight
              | FullHouse
              | Four
              | Three
              | Chance;
```

The scoring function is going to produce a `Hand * int` pair.

There are many ways to proceed; I choose to write classification functions based on structure rather than counting.

```
(* Utility function; 'all xs' is true if and only if none of its elements are false. *)
fun all [] = true
  | all (false :: ts) = false
  | all (_ :: ts) = all ts

(* These check the conditions for each type of roll. They all assume that the input is sorted. *)
fun is_yahtzee [a,b,c,d,e] = all [a = b, b = c, c = d, d = e]
  | is_yahtzee _ = false;

fun is_large_straight [a,b,c,d,e] = all [b = a + 1, c = b + 1, d = c + 1, e = d + 1]
  | is_large_straight _ = false;

fun is_small_straight [a,b,c,d,e] = all [b = a + 1, c = b + 1, d = c + 1, e <> d + 1]
                             orelse all [b <> a + 1, c = b + 1, d = c + 1, e = c + 1]
  | is_small_straight _ = false;

fun is_full_house [a,b,c,d,e] = all [a = b, b = c, c <> d, d = e]
                         orelse all [a = b, b <> c, c = d, d = e]
  | is_full_house _ = false;

fun is_four [a,b,c,d,e] = all [a = b, b = c, c = d, d <> e]
                   orelse all [a <> b, b = c, c = d, d = e]
  | is_four _ = false;

fun is_three [a,b,c,d,e] = all [a = b, b = c, c <> d, d <> e]
                    orelse all [a <> b, b = c, c = d, d <> e]
                    orelse all [a <> b, b <> c, c = d, d = e]
  | is_three _ = false;
```

With this, you can write down your scoring rules as a function in a pretty straightforward way:

```
(* Assumes that the input is sorted and has five elements. *)
fun score roll =
    let val value = sum roll in
        if is_yahtzee roll
        then (Yahtzee, 50)
        else if is_large_straight roll
        then (LargeStraight, 40)
        else if is_small_straight roll
        then (SmallStraight, 30)
        else if is_full_house roll
        then (if value > 25 then (Three, value) else (FullHouse, 25))
        else if is_four roll
        then (Four, value)
        else if is_three roll
        then (Three, value)
        else (Chance, value)
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I might refactor that.

To better be able to determine what roll I've got, I'd like to build a histogram of the dice:

```
fun histogram [] = []
  | histogram (d::ds) =
    let
      fun insert x [] = [(x, 1)]
        | insert x ((y,n) :: hist) =
            if x = y
            then (y,n+1) :: hist
            else (y,n) :: insert x hist
    in
      insert d (histogram ds)
    end

fun frequencyOf (x, []) = 0
  | frequencyOf (x, (y,n)::hist) =
      if x = y
      then n
      else frequencyOf (x, hist)

fun highestFrequency [] = 0
  | highestFrequency ((x,i)::hist) =
      Int.max (i, highestFrequency hist)
```

This way I can determine a yahtzee if there's only one element in the histogram, a straight if there's five, four-of-a-kind if the highest frequency is 4, and so on.

Then I'd like a custom data type to represent the kind of outcome,

**Edit:** Following molbdnilo, I also separated the score from the `roll` type entirely.

```
datatype roll
  = Yahtzee
  | LargeStraight
  | SmallStraight
  | FullHouse
  | FourOfAKind
  | ThreeOfAKind
  | Chance
```

And to determine the outcome,

```
fun determineDice (d1, d2, d3, d4, d5) =
    let
      val dice = ListMergeSort.sort (op >) [d1, d2, d3, d4, d5]
      val diceHistogram = histogram dice
    in 
      case length diceHistogram of
           1 => (Yahtzee, 50)
         | 2 => if highestFrequency diceHistogram = 4
                then (FourOfAKind, sum dice)
                else (FullHouse, 25)
         | 3 => if highestFrequency diceHistogram = 3
                then (ThreeOfAKind, sum dice)
                else (Chance, sum dice)
         | 4 => (Chance, sum dice)
         | 5 => if frequencyOf (6, dice) = 0
                then (SmallStraight, 30)
                else (LargeStraight, 40)
    end
```

For printing the outcome of a roll, I would write helper functions also:

```
fun showRoll Yahtzee = "Yahtzee"
  | showRoll LargeStraight = "Large straight"
  | ...
  | showRoll (Chance _) = "Chance"

fun showRollWithPoints (roll, points) =
    showRoll roll ^ " of " ^ Int.toString points ^ " points"
```

Some other improvements you could make:

- `determineDice` is a little shaky in that it accepts input that are outside the range of 1-6. You could either create a custom data type for dice, `datatype die = One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six`, and a function that picks a random one of these on top of `Random.randInt`,

  or you could create an abstract interface that does just use `int` internally, but does not allow exporting dice that are not 1-6. See [SML: What's the difference between using abstype and using a signature to hide the implementation of a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296795/sml-whats-the-difference-between-using-abstype-and-using-a-signature-to-hide-t)